# How to use attr in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

Is the use of the following code correct? I have to give more than one attribute to attr ?

```
<input data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': id, type: checkType()  }"/>
```

Comment: @Tushar https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Welcome........:)